# Is there a way to figure out what files is an application trying to open?

Tags: windows

Okay, I'll try to explain this as easily as I can, so please bear with me.

I have tracked down a copy of a certain application fow Windows, meaning it consists of more than one file.

While I don't want to share the name of this application, I'm quite sure it's freeware, because it's rather old and it exists like nowhere on the internet.

The guy, who has this copy, doesn't actually *share* it though. He just happened to make a back up of it on his server and I just happened to find it there.

But I can't download it as a whole, because directory listing isn't allowed on his server.

I have download the main file of the application, so I know that is what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I can't actually use it, because it crashes without the other files.

I just need to know the names of those files. Then I can download them.

---

*So, basically, I'm asking if there is any application for Windows, where you can open a certain process and whenewer the process tries to internally load a file, the path is stored there.*

A report of all processes together is also fine. I can find it there.

Thanks for the answer.

---

Edit: This guy's contact info is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be difficult and cumbersome to use, but the System Internals Process Monitor is what you need.

You can find it  [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

You will need to add a bunch of filters to get it to work for you as it monitors EVERYTHING happening outside of the windows kernel.  This is WAY TOO MUCH information for mere mortals.

Start by adding a filter to only include your exe name.  Then start adding filters to exclude the stuff you are sure you don't care about.

I have used this method to figure out all sorts of things about EXEs that I don't have the source code for.

***Hints:***

I find that adding a filter for `Result IS NOT SUCCESS` is good for the sort of thing you are trying to do here.

Right clicking on stuff within the list view can add filters on the fly but they might not do what you want.. play with it.