# CMD and GIT Bash Extremely Slow

Tags: windows-10, bash, git, cmd.exe

**My computer info:**

Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single
10.0.18362 N/A compilação 18362
Multiprocessor Free

**GIT Version**: 2.23.0.windows.1

When I open CMD, it open after 7, 8 seconds.

I when I type `git status` in some directory with project GIT, it show output after of the 7, 8 seconds.

My PC doesn't have AMD Radeon.

My enviroment variables are corrects.

I don't know more what to do.

Comment: Are you SURE your environment variables are all ok? Look especially at your path.    Open the command prompt.  Run another instance of cmd.exe from within that opened instance.  Still slow?  `set PATH=%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%`  Run cmd.exe again from that same instance.  Still slow?

Comment: "Yes" to the three asks. =(

Comment: Well.. I will tell you "the hard way" to figure this out.. See an [unrelated post](https://superuser.com/questions/1473778/is-there-a-way-to-figure-out-what-files-is-an-application-trying-to-open/1473788#1473788) I wrote.. it can solve ANYTHING that isn't in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542488/2756335.

Someone has pointed out that changing the drivers worked for them but for me setting HOME in system variables did the trick. Please refer to the steps -

- Right-click on "Computer" in file explorer.
- Open Advanced System Settings.
- Open Environment Variables.
- Under System Variables, click "New..."
- Enter "HOME" for the variable name and the path to your user directory for the value (for example "C:\Users\jdoe").

Comment: It works fine with User Variables.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the problem and I traced it to the default prompt string (`$PS1`). By default it calls a `__git_ps1` function that issues several git commands to decorate the command prompt. This can take a while on large projects.

So I created my own `.profile` that defines a plain PS1.

Comment: But he said that just cmd.exe was also slow to open.  It shouldn't have anything to do with the windows git bash shell.

Comment: This also sped up the startup time of the Git Bash window.